# Lost .dat file but

Tags: lost-wallet

I lost an old .dat file with 1.5 BTC balance.

I created it with Bitcoin qt 0.8.6, I still have that exact program on my SD card.

I once heard each bitcoin qt wallet does contain a pool of about 100 addresses. Isn't my lost adress supposed to be in that program ? Can I re-generate the adress with that old qt ? If not what can I do ? Nothing I guess...

Comment: Yes it generates a pool of future addresses, but those are stored in your `wallet.dat` file. Without the file, there is unfortunately nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot recover control over the Bitcoin amount associated with the addresses in your old wallet data file unless you have a [backup of the wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=Securing_your_wallet&redirect=no#Backup) or a note of the [private key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key).